# Pass prop to nested element in styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to pass a prop to a nested style for a paragraph element, but it looks like I can't put the prop directly on the element. How do I achieve this? I only want to apply the uppercase transformation to only one of the p elements...

```js
const MailingListWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  & > p {
    text-transform: ${props => props.uppercase || 'none'};
  }
`

function JoinUs() {
  return (
    <MailingListWrapper>
      <p uppercase="uppercase">Join our mailing list!</p>
      <p>Never miss an update</p>
    </MailingListWrapper>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `props` you have access to in the template string used when creating the `MailingListWrapper` component are the props given to `MailingListWrapper` when you use it.

You could instead give the `p` tag a `uppercase` `className` and just apply the styles to `p` tags with the `uppercase` class.

```
const MailingListWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  & > p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
`;

function JoinUs() {
  return (
    <MailingListWrapper>
      <p className="uppercase">Join our mailing list!</p>
      <p>Never miss an update</p>
    </MailingListWrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: In that case I would have to create two styles, one for each p element? If I want both of them to have the color: gold, how do I share that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting the final result here for posterity based on Tholle's answer...

```js
const MailingListWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  & > p {
    color: gold;
    &.uppercase {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
`
```